# Biber stopped working for no apparent reason

Tags: biber

I do not understand what happened. I am on TexStudio and usually I would compile, then run Biber, and then recompile and there would be no issue.

Now, it does not work. After I compile and then run Biber I receive these messages

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.17
INFO - Logfile is '2thesisdraft.blg'
INFO - Reading '2thesisdraft.bcf'
INFO - Found 65 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'All.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'All.bib'

Process exited with error(s)
```

and the log shows says this,

```
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) 2thesisdraft(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

When I rerun Biber, I just get the same messages as above. Anyone know what could be wrong? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
hyperref=true,
backref=true,
natbib=true,
sorting=nyt,
abbreviate=true]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{% Clean up the bibtex rather than editing it
    \clearfield{doi}
    \clearfield{url}
    \clearfield{issn}
    \clearlist{location}
    \clearfield{month}
    \clearfield{series}
    
    \ifentrytype{book}{}{% Remove publisher and editor except for books
        \clearlist{publisher}
        \clearname{editor}
    }
}
\addbibresource{All.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{bonder.groisman:09:global}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\printbibliography[title={References}]
\end{document}
```

Here is a minimal All.bib file:

```
    @Article{bonder.groisman:09:global,
  author        = {Bonder, F. and Groisman, P.},
  title         = {Space time white noise eliminates and global solutions in reaction diffusion equations},
  journal       = {Physica D},
  year          = {2009},
  number        = {238},
  pages         = {209--215}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal Working Example so that people can test your code. Thank you.

Comment: perhaps the cache is broken. Run `biber --cache` to find its location, delete it and then try again.

Comment: There are no citation commands in that document. I assume the real one has them? Are you able to create a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) including a minimal bib file that by itself shows the problem?

Comment: @frabjous added a citation and a bib file.

Comment: `\printbibliography[title={References}` needs to be `\printbibliography[title={References}]`. That fixed, it works for me.

Comment: @frabjous Sorry... that was a typo on my part. That was already included in the actual file on my computer and is not the cause for my error.

Comment: If you get the error even with the minimal sample file posted, then follow Ulrike's advice and clean the cache and delete any other auxiliary files.

Anything in the .blg file beyond what you posted above?

Comment: @frabjous deleting the cache did the trick!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that was the fix! If you want, you can write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.